# Space around radio button to big

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, radio-button

I'm working on one large site and currently all radio buttons look like this:

[image]

In my View I have this code:

```
@Html.RadioButton("new", "new", false, new { @onclick = "New()", @id = "new", @class="radio-button" }) Some Text
```

And CSS for radio button:

```
.radio-button label {
  width:5px;
}
```

That width doesn't change anything. How can I remove all that space around radio button and have text near radio button? I was looking in that generated CSS Site.css but I can't find where it's defined to be like that.

Thank you!

Comment: without having more CSS code to look at, I'd recommend you look at `padding` / `margin`. Width won't affect much on an inline element such as `<label>`.

Comment: May you pass your URL?.. we could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you definig input width in somewhere else? Its not semantical ,but try

```
margin:0;
padding:0;    
width:5px!important;
```

If it works, try to "inspect element" with Developer Tools(chrome) to see if it hav any inheritance

Comment: Thank you. I inspected it with Developer Tools and I see in Site.css where the width is put to 300px. I just needed that.